# How to get data from an observer 'sales_quote_product_add_after'

Tags: product, event-observer, quote

I have applied this event in my **config.xml** but I dont know how to get data from this observer. I googled but no article found.

**config.xml**--

```
<sales_quote_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <po>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>po/observer</class>
            <method>updateQuote</method>
        </po>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_product_add_after>
```

**Observer file-**

```
public function updateQuote($observer)
{
    Mage::log("testing");
    $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItems();
    $quote = $quoteItem->getQuote();
    $id = $quote->getId();
    Mage::log($id."hello testing");
}
```

Getting only "testing" in log file and not getting "hello testing". How can I get info about product added into quote and info of the quote.

Comment: the `Mage::log` syntax is incorrect probably

Comment: That I did consiously to see whether I get data in var $id or not and it show only sdfds in log file.

Comment: I want to iterate loop only one time and only for that product that has been added not for all product that have been added before.

Answer (score 4):

This event is written as follow:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(‘sales_quote_product_add_after’, array(‘items’ => $items));
```

Means, we can grab `items` as follow: `$observer->getEvent()->getItems()`. And this will be an array of items.

```
public function updateQuote($observer)
{
    Mage::log("testing", null, 'quote-log.log');
    $items = $observer->getEvent()->getItems();

    foreach($items as $item){
      Mage::log($item->getId()."hello testing", null, 'quote-log.log');

    }
}
```

Now check file called `quote-log.log` in your `var/log` folder.

I haven't tested, but should work.

Comment: hello Adarsh, I did not get print `$item->getId()`, only prints `hello testing`

Comment: check my update answer

Comment: No it did not worked as I need. It prints 2 times for a single product and item id is also null.

Comment: do u want to get product id?

Comment: No, I need item Id from table quote_item

Comment: what happens if u change this `$item->getProduct()->getId()` to `$item->getQuoteId()`?

Comment: It gives me quote id not item id

Comment: What about $item->getItemId()?

Comment: it is not working. and I want it.

Comment: getId() should give you what you r looking for.

Comment: I found strange thing that If I use `getId()` and if i re-add same product then It gives me item_id. but first time it does not work.while I need at first time.

Comment: Did you solve the mystery?

Comment: No, It still exist, Is  there any event which is fired just after a product is set into quote ?

Comment: You can try with this event `sales_quote_add_item`

Comment: I have applied this event also still not getting item id using this code-`$item->getItemId()` or `$item->getId()`  It may be that we are using wrong code to get item id.

Comment: Hello Adarash, I am doing the same thing with another way, check my this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103928/create-duplicate-quote-item-instead-of-updating-existing-quote-item-for-same-pro

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItems()` instead of `$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();`

Comment: @nimesh..it Did not worked

Comment: check function is call by writing echo exit in function

Comment: If function not call then provide config.xml all code

Comment: This event trigger from "<root>\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php" function is "addProductAdvanced" line no 1025

Comment: check my updated question.