# Create Duplicate quote item instead of updating existing quote item for same product

Tags: event-observer, quote, sales-quote

**Requirement--**

I have created a custom Purchase Order module for my Magento Store, in which a same product may be supplied from many suppliers. You will be fully cleared from below

**example-**

**(1)** A product **P1** has been supplied to my store from three supplier say **S1, S2 and S3** with quantity **5,10,15** respectively.
Now I want to show SUM of all quantities i.e **(30=5+10+15)** to catalog inventory Stock. till Now there is no problem in doing this.

**(2)** Now When same product **P1** is added to cart(Either frontend or backend) with **qty 5** or less the  there is no problem, order process will be Normal(as default). But if qty of same product **P1** is added or updated greater than 5 **(let's say 8)** in quote then two rows(one row with **qty 5** and second row with **qty 3**) should be created in sales_quote_item table corresponding to supplier S1 and S2, but in cart (i.e. visisble to user On frontend and Backend as well) there should be only one row having qty 8. Same as if product P1 is added or updated with qty lets say **20** then there should be three rows corresponding to each supplier having qty **5, 10 and 5** but user should see only one row having qty **20.**

**(3)** If user place order of this product **P1** with qty **20** then three rows should be there in **sales_order_item** table with their qty.

**(4)** **In invoice** that will be printed out also should have single row for that product **P1**, so customer can see only one row of that product, he doesnt need to know about suppliers.

**(5)** **In credit memo** there should be three rows so admin can decide himself, product of which supplier should be returned .

**What I am trying Now--**

I am following **"fschmengler"** approach. I am trying to modify quote items while they are being converted to Order. Now I am stuck at How can I modify **price** and **totals** according to changed qty in sales table and How can I add same product multi-times in sales table and then recalculate order totals. I am using event `sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item`

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 3):

To change what's getting added to the cart you need to observe an event *before* the quote item is created. This way you can choose to update the qty of an existing item, add one or more new items, or both. Unfortunateley there is no event between `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()` and `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addProduct()`, so if you don't find a crazy workaround, you'll have to rewrite one of the methods in this control flow:

[image: Add product to cart sequence diagram]

I'd suggest `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addProductAdvanced()` because this is where `addItem()` is called. Also, manipulating the product options and merging alone will not work because of the case where you want to *add several new items* (7 => 5 + 2)

To create separate items for the same product, i.e. prevent that they get merged again, it's enough to add an invisible custom option to each item with a unique value.

Another possible approach would be to observe `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` which is called every time you visit the cart, and then rearrange the quote.

For each product that should be treated like this:
- check for items with qty > 5
- reduce the qty of those items to 5
- if there are items with qty < 5, add remaining qty up to 5
- add new items for the remaining qty (again, with a unique custom option)

Comment: Hello fschmengler, thanks for your detailed answer but please check my updated question.

Comment: If you only need the separation in the backend and the user must not see it, you should not alter the quote at all and modify the order items instead, when the quote is converted to an order.

Comment: I have no idea how can I do it what have you said, can you add some code snippet if you have a chance.

Comment: Why should the order totals change?

Comment: yeah  fschmengler, I just got wrong thought, sorry for my comment, just deleted it. But how can I duplicate an item to order while converting from quote.? Like product p1 (qty-5) in quote should be in two rows with qty(3) and qty(2)

Comment: You can change qty, and row totals for an item and create new instances that you add with `$order->addItem()`. Please try it out and update the question or create a new one if you encounter problems. I did not do something like that yet so I don't have ready-to-use code for you.

Comment: Yea, I have created new question for my problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105534/how-to-modify-sales-item-or-add-new-item-before-saving-order

Answer (score 0):

Method `representProduct` inside class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` is responsible for comparing 2 items in quote and their merging behavior in one. You can create some rewrite for the method to check if the qty in cart is as you require. This should be straightforward to achieve.

That function is called by `getItemByProduct` function inside class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`, so if you don't want control over option level in items, you can try re-writing that method too. Product being added to the cart will be available as the `$product` object. This function is called from the function `_addCatalogProduct` in same class, which holds the qty as well. This is the qty which is requested to be added into the cart in current request cycle.

Comment: If I do `Mage::log(count($this->getAllItems()))` in function `getItemByProduct` , and when I add a product to quote then it shows `0` count in system.log but I think count should be  `1` and when I add second product in quote then count shows `1` and shows `2` on adding third item. Why it is showing this behaviour.?

Comment: It's because that function is executed before actually adding product to cart. It controls whether the product being added to cart should be added as a new item or it should increase qty of a previous item.

Comment: If I am unable to retrieve item then how can I edit that item info?

Comment: @shashank, I have updated the answer with more details.

Comment: Ok Is there not any event which can fulfill my need.?

Comment: As I have checked If I update any quote product then above  function is not called then in this case how can check product qty?

Comment: `_addCatalogProduct` function should be called in case of qty update too. Did you check with some sort of logging ? Events I know about, work only after the product is already added to cart, like `sales_quote_product_add_after`.

Comment: Hello Prateek, I am still working on my question..I have updated it please check it again if you have a chance.

Comment: For that, I'd suggest following the fschmengler's advice as he mentioned in his comment. You might figure something out at `sales_order_place_before` event.

Comment: Using this event `sales_order_place_before`, will I be able to edit all quote items, I mean will I be able to make 2 separate rows with different quantities for same product?

Comment: Event has all the data related to the order that is going to be saved. You should be able to modify that before the quote item gets converted to order item. There is also an event with the name `sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item` which converts each quote item to order item. It is called in `itemToOrderItem` function in `Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote` class which is again called from `submitOrder` function from `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote` class. Check if you find anything interesting at those locations.

Comment: Although I have not found that How can I modify quote item or add new quote item while converting it to an order also if I will be able to do it then I am thinking about the reorder case. If I reorder an order which has multi rows of a product then it will be duplicated in quote table as well. But I think there I will need to use an observer on event while converting sales order item to quote item. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that would be an approach for that. Although, just out of curiosity, could you tell why exactly you need this sort of functionality ?

Comment: I have developed custom Purchase order module in which a product is being supplied from different suppliers.

Comment: I need to merge all qty of that product into one while showing quote to user but need separate entries in sale tables so at the time of credit memo I can select that product from which supplier should be returned.

Comment: Another problem that i am getting if I use observer  `sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item` If I change qty of product then how can I change totals for that product row. Like if I change qty 1 to 2 while converting quote to order then still sales row shows price according to qty1, it is not being updated with qty2, how can I do it.?

Comment: You should try partial creditmemos for that. The way you are going, you'll need to re-write a lot of sales related functionality in core Magento, I don't believe that others would like this much modification, if you intend to make it community accessible. With partial memos, you can split how much qty should be returned from an order, this way you should be able to achieve something viable. I seriously doubt that events alone would be of much help in there.

Comment: Hi Prateek I am getting problem to achieve my goal see this question if you can answer. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105534/how-to-modify-sales-item-or-add-new-item-before-saving-order